# Error connecting to oracle database g11 release 2 in Java

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to connect to a remote oracle database server in Java with the following code:

```
public static Connection getConexionOracle () {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.vital.com.mx:1521:XE","username","password");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

I am using Oracle g11 Releas 2 and I already included the ojdbc.jar in my build path. 
When trying to establish the connection, I get the following stack trace error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at vital.tde.general.Conexion.getConexionOracle(Conexion.java:22)
 [java]     at vital.tde.general.Prueba.doGet(Prueba.java:35)
 [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 [java]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 [java]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
 [java]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
 [java]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
 [java]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
 [java]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 [java]     at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392)
 [java]     at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434)
 [java]     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687)
 [java]     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:247)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
 [java]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
 [java]     ... 26 more
 [java] Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: //oracle.vital.com.mx
 [java]     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:117)
 [java]     at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
 [java]     at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370)
 [java]     ... 31 more
```

I already tried the following and I still get the error:

1. Ping oracle.vital.com.mx (get response)
2. Telnet oracle.vital.com.mx 1521 (get response)
3. Disable Server Firewall

Which solution do you suggest to this problem? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same Q on multiple sites again.  It's considered abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [java] Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: //oracle.vital.com.mx
```

Try removing "//" in your connection string.

Comment: Im able to connecto now to the database, but when performing a query in Java, it says that the table doesnt exist, but through the Oracle Application Express I write the same query and it executes correctly. Do you know why could this happen?

Comment: Most likely a schema issue.  Your original problem is solved. Now you have a new one.

Comment: Yes I had to include the schema name before the table name and now is working. thanks

Comment: When you have a nested stack trace like this, you should always have a good look at the original cause of the problem, which is the one at the _bottom_.   All the rest is just to tell you how you got there.  In this case it is an UnknownHostException.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I try this and it works:

-- Execute this command from your Oracle server machine
   $lsnrctl services
   it gives you the disponible services.

-- Put the values of "HOST" and "PORT" of the external service (the name of this service is something like "XDB.your.domain") on your java's url string connection.

Good luck!

PS: Sorry for my english.

I see you resolve the connection problem. Well if in the future you have some issue with remote connection you have my answer.